# Removing a border from an inlineshape - Word crash

Tags: vba, image, ms-word, border

I have reused a code from this link: [how to remove a border from an inline shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588789/how-to-remove-a-border-from-an-inline-shape).
My code has additional conditional instruction for specific inlinshapes.
The code looks like this:

```
Sub Picture_no_Border()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim iShp As InlineShape


    For Each iShp In ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
        With iShp
            If .Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then
                If Len(.Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text) = 2 Then
                    With .Line
                        .Visible = False
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It works when the number of pictures is small in my document. However, when I have a document with around 150 pictures then MS Word crashes and stops working. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: I would check which shape it crashes on.

Comment: You existing code makes the border invisible. Instead try formatting it away altogether: `With .Line
    .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255,255,255)
    .Weight = 0
End With`

Comment: I'd put a `DoEvents` in your `for` loop, generally helps relieve some load.

Comment: DoEvents has almost done the job so thank You a lot but I still do not understand why it was so problematic for a program to go through 150 objects ?

Comment: You might also try using .Borders.Enable = False instead of .Line.Visible = False

Comment: I have checked the document. I deleted most of the content. I left only the first chapter in which there are 2 inline shapes,i.e., two pictures. It occurs that in the locals window the macro gives a bizzare number 181 for n variable when `n = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count 
Debug.Print n` is executed. Still I do not understand where does this number come from as n should be equal to two?